# Confusion regarding the conservation of mechanical energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation

If it's always the case that---when all forces are derivable from a potential energy---$$\Delta T = W = -\Delta V$$ so that $$\Delta \left(T + V\right) = 0,$$ why is energy *not* conserved when $V$ is time-dependent? More precisely, what's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: What is your reasoning? I don't see any reasoning presented here. You have given equations and then asked a question.

Comment: @AaronStevens $\Delta T = W = -\Delta V \implies \Delta (T + V) = 0$

Comment: That is true for conservative forces. I am confused about what this means for time-dependence

Comment: @AaronStevens Even with time-dependence, $W = -\Delta V$, no?

Comment: Are you asking about explicit time dependence? Like a potential energy function $V=V(\mathbf r,t)$? Or implicit time dependence like $V=V(\mathbf r(t))$?

Comment: @AaronStevens The former.

Comment: Please explain the situation you are thinking about more clearly - what do $T,W,V$ and their $\Delta$s denote, exactly? Note that "kinetic energy" and "potential energy" are not precise enough here - why is $V$ time-dependent? What do you mean by unqualified "energy" here and why do you think it is not conserved? Remember that we cannot read your mind and are lacking the larger context you're presumably asking this question in.

Comment: @ACuriousMind $V$ is time-dependent because there's nothing that says it can't be. How many definitions of "kinetic energy" and "potential energy" do you know? $T = \frac{1}{2}\sum_\alpha m_\alpha v_\alpha^2$, $V = \sum V_\alpha^\textrm{ext} + \sum_\alpha \sum_{\beta > \alpha} V_{\alpha\beta}$, $E = T + V$.

Comment: Let's be concrete here and say the time-variant potential is due to an electric field and some lab assistant is turning up the current producing the electric field. What is "energy" here? The energy of a particle in the field? The energy of a partial *and* the field? The energy of millions of particles in the field, the field *and* the rest of the universe? All these "energies" are different and have different explanations for why they may or may not be conserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work done on a particle over some interval of time $[t_1,t_2]$ is

$$ W = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \vec F_{net} \cdot \frac{d\vec x}{dt} dt$$

If we assume that $\vec F_{net} = - \nabla V(\vec x)$ then

$$W = - \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \nabla V(x(t)) \cdot \frac{d\vec x}{dt} dt = - \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{d}{dt}\left(V(\vec x(t))\right)dt$$
$$ = - [V(x(t_f))-V(x(t_i))] \equiv -\Delta V $$

This is a result of the chain rule:
$$\frac{d}{dt} V(\vec x(t)) = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt} \equiv \nabla V \cdot \frac{d\vec x}{dt}$$

However, if $V$ is an explicit function of time, then

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \vec V(\vec x(t), t) = \nabla V \cdot \frac{d\vec x}{dt} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} $$

and that second term ruins everything.  The work becomes

$$ W = - \Delta V + \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} dt$$

And so the total energy $E = T+V$ is not conserved.

Answer (score 2):

So your first equation only applies when the forces that do the work $W$ you are interested in are conservative forces whose work is accounted for in $\Delta V$. So it is not "always the case". In general
$$\Delta(T+V)=W_{other}$$
where $W_{other}$ is the work done by other forces that are either not conservative or that are conservative but you are not taking into account for in $\Delta V$.

If your potential energy function has an explicit time dependence such that $V=V(\mathbf r,t)$ then if you might find your potential (and hence total mechanical energy) changing without any work being done on the object. For example, if I were to hold a charged particle still in a time varying electric field, then its potential energy would be changing as the field changes, yet the charge is not moving so no work is being done on it.

Of course if you were to make your system larger to include the cause of the time varying field then you will get energy conservation back. You can always make your system large enough so that the entire system's energy is constant, even if the energy of its constituents might be changing.

Comment: See my edit. Can you explicitly point out why $\Delta (T + V) = 0$ is wrong or why it doesn't mean that the energy of the system is conserved?

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy I did that in my answer.